# Doesn't TableView generate didSelectRowAtIndexPath event when selection is made programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have used the following code to programmatically select tableview cells

```
- (void) selectTableCell{
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];

NSIndexPath *ip1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:ip1 animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];}
```

For testing purposes I wanted to do this. How do I generate the didselect event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation explicitly tells you what happens:

> Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message, nor will it send `UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification` notifications to observers.

You could try to call these methods yourself but you are not guaranteed that will replicate the original functionality.

To test your UI, you should probably use the Instruments-based UI Automation Testing if possible.

Answer (score 5):

I guess this should work:

```
if ([tableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
    [tableView.delegate tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:ip];
}
```

Comment: nope.. I mean it just runs the method.. the event doesn't get fired

Comment: If you right what med200 suggests below your call at selectRowAtIndexPath it should call didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method